# fulfillment shopify api not working 2023-01

Tags: api, shopify, fulfillment

I am trying to use this api /fulfillments.json in shopify but i am getting error {"errors":"Not Found"}

my code is here

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://logixgrid-save.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/fulfillments.json' \
--header 'X-Shopify-Access-Token: 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' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "fulfillment": {
        "message": "The package was shipped this morning.",
        "notify_customer": false,
        
        "tracking_info": {
            "number": 1562678,
            "url": "https://www.my-shipping-company.com",
            "company": "my-shipping-company"
        },
        "line_items_by_fulfillment_order": [
            {
                "fulfillment_order_id": 5247929286964,
                
                "fulfillment_order_line_items": [
                    {
                        "id": 1058737495,
                        "quantity": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

Here is my test store detail you can try this i will delete all these after 2 days

i am getting this response

{"errors":"Not Found"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is because `1058737495` id was took directly from documentation and you don't have such line_item in your order.

EDIT: Your fulfillment order id is wrong. You can get correct one by fetching `/admin/api/2023-01/orders/{{ order.id}}/fulfillment_orders.json`. This will return array of fulfillment orders. Try one of the ids - it should be working.

```
curl -X GET "https://redacted.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/orders/5250054553908/fulfillment_orders.json" \
-H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: shpca_redacted"
```

Comment: You can remove this one without line item try this line item is not required

Comment: @TwistedOwl is right. "Not found" error means either the fulfillment order or its line item is not found. Remove `fulfillment_order_line_items` completely since the `1058737495` line item id probably doesn't exist or fetch one dynamically.

Comment: @GenevièveM. this api does not work I have tried your idea also

Comment: @JaskaranSingh This is strange. Did you check that (1) a fulfillment order with id `5247929286964` exists in your store, (2) you have all required access scopes, (3) your access token is not expired ?

Comment: Not found says that the fulfillment order id is invalid and doesn't exist. Can you post the result of the fulfillment_orders.json get request?

Comment: @TwistedOwl greate

Comment: @JaskaranSingh good to hear its fixed :)

Comment: I'm trying to get a `fulfillment_order_id` in Python by using `requests.get(url)` with the following URL: `https://redacted.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/orders/4754292932796/fulfillment_orders.json`. The order_id `4754292932796` has been found by separately using the endpoint `https://redacted.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/orders.json?limit=250` and fetching the value of the `id` field. I am able to verify that I can fulfil the order with the now deprecated method from 2021-07, i.e. the order ID seems correct. But I get `{'fulfillment_orders': []}`

Comment: I am also getting {'fulfillment_orders': []}. Did you ever figure out how to fix this?

Comment: hi `reason of the empty fulfillment_orders means missing permissions `{'fulfillment_orders': []}, you must give following permissions inaddition to current permissions; `read_merchant_managed_fulfillment_orders,write_merchant_managed_fulfillment_orders,write_assigned_fulfillment_orders,read_assigned_fulfillment_orders`